# Too many redirects ONLY in IOS?

Tags: web-config, mobile-safari, joomla3.0, iis-8

This site works fine everywhere except in IOS.
http://www.pepedivecenter.com.

- It works in Windows with Firefox, Chrome or IE.
- It works in OSX with Safari or Chrome
- It works in Android phones
- **BUT, it does not work in IOS (iPhone or iPad) using Chrome or Safari!**

When I try to open the site in an iPad or an IPhone with Chrome or Safari I get a **TOO MANY REDIRECTS** error.

The web.config is pretty clean:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="PHP_via_FastCGI" />
            <add name="PHP_via_FastCGI" path="*.php" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\php\php-cgi.exe|-d open_basedir='D:\XVRT\pepedivecenter.com\Html;D:\XVRT\pepedivecenter.com\html\new'" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Script" />
        </handlers>
        <security>
            <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="true">
            </ipSecurity>
        </security>
        <staticContent>
            <remove fileExtension=".htm" />
            <remove fileExtension=".html" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".html" mimeType="text/html" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".htm" mimeType="text/html" />
        </staticContent>

    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I tried enabling and disabling the friendly urls,
the site is running under IIS so I tried several configurations with web.config

I cleaned joomla's cache and redirects.

I cleaned the browsers cache and cookies.

I updated everything to the last version (joomla 3.6.5)
but the problem continues.

How can I troubleshoot this problem? any ideas?

tks!

Comment: Not a Chrome Apps question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround.
The problem was caused by the Joomla plugin "System - Language Filter".
I disabled this plugin and now the site works in IOS.